# Is repeating COUNT(*) in a MySQL query expensive?

Tags: mysql, performance, count, aggregate-functions

```
SELECT 
    author_fname, 
    author_lname, 
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN '1 book'
        ELSE CONCAT(COUNT(*), ' books')
    END AS 'No. of books'
FROM books
GROUP BY author_fname, author_lname;
```

I call COUNT(*) twice in this query even though the result is the same. Does MySQL automatically knows that it doesn't have to recalculate this value?

If not, how can I make this query more efficient by not repeating COUNT(*)?

Comment: `SELECT` from another `SELECT` if you really care: `SELECT f,l,c FROM (SELECT .... GROUP BY ...)`.

Comment: This looks like a basic optimization task for the query planner.

Comment: As a note this is a display concern and should be done in the application layer, not the database layer.

Comment: It will probably only run it once since it will be getting the aggregate together in intermediate result set in order to produce the final result set. You could always toss the aggregate (without the case) into a subquery and then do this last `CASE` stuff outside the aggregation to be certain.

Comment: Usually SQL do not execute such function calls more than once in a single query. However, I do not remember if this is mentioned somewhere in manual. For your situation: I would not do this at all. It is not up to DB to build "representation". It is up to app/view. Just return the count and do the rest there.

Answer (score 1):

I believe MySQL has COUNT(*) optimized to where it is not really expensive at all (just a running total of rows, rather than a live count); but for more complicated aggregation, such as `COUNT(DISTINCT someField)`, subqueries are often the best option.

```
SELECT author_fname, author_lname 
   , CASE WHEN myCalc = 1 THEN '1 book'
          ELSE CONCAT(myCalc, ' books')
    END AS 'No. of books'
FROM (
   SELECT author_fname, author_lname, COUNT(*) AS myCalc
   FROM books
   GROUP BY author_fname, author_lname
) AS q
;
```

That said, I'm not sure whether MySQL is smart enough to perform `MAX(a+b+c*d)` only once if it occurs numerous times in one query. I would hope it would, and would not be surprised it already does; but I've never come across any documentation confirming it.

Comment: You can use `EXPLAIN` to see exactly how MySQL will go about executing your query.  See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html.  (This displays the so-called "execution plan," which is what actually drives the database engine as it carries out your query.)

Comment: Also:  `COUNT(*)` is sometimes "the cheapest summary statistic of all," since it is often found in the "statistics" metadata for the table.

Comment: @MikeRobinson yeah, that was what I meant by "just a running total".

Comment: @MikeRobinson - `COUNT(*)` is _not_ available anywhere, with one exception:  MyISAM, with neither a `WHERE`, nor a `GROUP BY`.  Also, `EXPLAIN` won't give needed the detail.

Comment: I would expect this subquery approach to take much longer than the original query.  It needs to make an extra pass over at least the output rows.

Comment: Yeah, that is a good note by @RickJames that I completely overlooked for some reason, COUNT(*) is only really optimized for whole table counts, any where or grouping means it goes the long way around or is dependent on indexes. That said, I think the benefit of the subquery approach may depend on the data and whether or not MySQL in fact only calculates the COUNT(*) twice. If there are actually few combinations, the final CASE will only be performed over very few rows; and if MySQL recalculates COUNT(*) for each use, that outer CASE could be less expensive.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, evaluating expressions (whether repeated or not) take *much* less time than fetching the rows involved in the query.  So, don't worry about it.